# Star Rating not rendering on custom HTML email in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, css, html5

We have created an email in Marketing cloud using an existing **Blank template** where we can drop our custom made content blocks.

And for one email we have a requirement where we need to capture the survey response from the end user.

And for capturing the response we wanted to use the star rating approach and to create a star rating we are using a  tag of type "radio" and in that input tag, we are adding a label and anchor tag for the link.

When we view the outcome of the code in Marketing cloud then it is showing fine and rendering is also OK but when we are using that custom HTML block in the email then when a user is receiving it on **Gmail then they are seeing a radio button and a small star** see SS below and for Gmail the stars are going to the extreme left:

[image]

**And when a user is viewing the same on outlook then this is the output and for Outlook the stars are going to the extreme right with bracket besides them:**

[image]

**See How it is showing when viewed in a browser or in Marketing Cloud tool or in Service cloud's custom HTML template:**
This is when a user gives a 5-star rating

[image]

This is when a user gives a 4-star rating and so one the color is changing

[image]

Please let me know how can we achieve this using HTML or CSS or any other approach in the marketing cloud.

Please let me know if you have any queries regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually not best practice to have form controls within a email. Your issue may be arising from how different ISPs treat form inputs in emails.

I've worked on similar functionality before. Instead of radio buttons we just used images which link to a landing page with a parameter that then writes to a DE, the rating and subscriber key or email address. see below for example.

[image: Rate Email]

Comment: A solution like this is really the only reliable solution. There is very little support on not just the styling, but also the posting/submission of forms from HTML email. This is due to the potential security risk it inherently brings by allowing personal info to pass outside of the ISP.

Comment: Hi Noor, we are also using this approach. We have added an image instead of a radio button and now when a user clicks on the image they are redirected to the portal to complete there feedback.